# ASP.NET Ajax Calendar

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar

I am using MS AJAX ASP.NET Components (Calendar Extender) and I'm finding this problem.

Some weekdays are not being displayed....

I uploaded a picture so you can view exactly how it is being displayed...

The one on the right (calnder) in the picture is taken from microsoft's sample.

Have you got any idea what is causing this problem?

See screenshot: http://www.sajtkik.com/calendar.jpg

Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that your page CSS affects this calendar markup.
You can use FireBug to see which of the CSS rules produce such effect.

Comment: Yes Sir I had a mistake in the CSS FILE!! 10x mate :)

Comment: I think I had the same problem (the link to the image in the question is no longer working). For me, it was that I put padding (padding-right) on all <td> elements in my page. This was pushing the Saturday and Sunday columns out of view. I rectified it by removing the padding.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen enough odd behavior when it comes to using MS "Ajax" objects across different browsers, to recommend not using the Calendar object if it can be avoided.  There are enough client side (JS) libraries out there for calendars that are significantly better.

Why not try a [jQuery calendar](http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-calendar-version-2)?

Comment: Jeff Crossett answered this one first 10x

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know much about javascript to use JQuery. It's more simple than Javascript and just a few lines of code you can use JQuery Calendar on your page.

But of course being good needs some efforts.

Comment: HEY THANKS ALOT! I MANAGED TO USE JQUERY+CALENDAR! WELLDONE 10x

Comment: Glad to help you. JQuery rocks, that is what I know about JQuery.